# What are anchor points?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I already tried reading this: http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/
But I got lost in the second example. (how does an anchor point of ccp(-1,-1) mean “Place the anchor 1 * myWidth to the left and 1 * myHeight under the sprite”?) Can somebody explain how anchor points work to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An anchor point is defined relative to the sprite. E.g., if the anchor point is (0,0), then it is at the left-bottom corner; if (1,1), at the right-top corner; if (0.5, 0.5), at the center.

So, an anchor point at (-1, -1), means that it lays *outside* of the sprite, at the coordinates that you mention in your question. This is the opposite to the right-top corner respect to the let-bottom corner (trace a diagonal from the right-top corner to the left-bottom corner, extend it beyond the latter point and take the symmetric to the right-top corner).

If you think that scaling and rotation (and other properties) are defined relative to the anchor point, then if you set the anchor point at (-1, -1) and rotate the sprite, you will see the sprite describe a circle (this is rotating plus translating).

Comment: Thank you; it's clearer now. But why was the black box moved up-right when the anchor point was set to (-1,-1)?

Comment: Because the texture position is also relative to the anchor point and each time the sprite is redrawn the current anchor point is taken into account (besides the origin coord).

Answer (score 1):

See this link for an interactive demo what anchors are: http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layers/examples/placementdemo/ Should you tell more than long narrative descriptions.